# How to make RGB LED blink rapidly one color using FOR or WHILE loop

Tags: rgb-led

I found a code that turns on different RGB colors but I would like it to blink rapidly one color once called. I dont want to use void loop function to make this possible. My RGB is a cathode. Any help?

```
int redPin = 8;
int greenPin = 9;
int bluePin = 10;

//uncomment this line if using a Common Anode LED
//#define COMMON_ANODE

void setup()
{
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop()
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) //LED simply stays on. No blinking occuring
     {
      setColor(255, 0, 0);
      delay(100);
      setColor(0, 0, 0);
        }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
  #ifdef COMMON_ANODE
    red = 255 - red;
    green = 255 - green;
    blue = 255 - blue;
  #endif
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(greenPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluePin, blue);  
}
```

Comment: You need another delay as the last line in the for loop.  Currently it is turning it off and then immediately turning it on at the top of the loop.

Comment: give another delay after `setColor(0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
int redPin = 8;
int greenPin = 9;
int bluePin = 10;

//uncomment this line if using a Common Anode LED
//#define COMMON_ANODE

void setup()
{
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  blinkLed();
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
#ifdef COMMON_ANODE
  red = 255 - red;
  green = 255 - green;
  blue = 255 - blue;
#endif
  analogWrite(redPin, red);
  analogWrite(greenPin, green);
  analogWrite(bluePin, blue);
}

void blinkLed()
{
  setColor(255, 0, 0);  // red
  delay(1000);
  setColor(0, 0, 0);  // off
  delay(1000);
}
```

This snippet will blink your led in the red color. Put it in your void loop and you are ready to go.

NOTE: Erase the rest of the void loop before putting this in. Don't delete the function though.

**EDIT**

FULL CODE ADDED

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using loop function? Say with a while or for loop? I'm actually using this function within a code.

Comment: Yes you can, simply insert it in whatever loop you want

Comment: I tried but the LED stays on

Comment: I've included the FULL code. If it doesn't work, describe in detail what happens.